# heatmap.js show colorless circle in microsoft edge

Tags: javascript, microsoft-edge, heatmap

I have a problem with the library heatmap.js. I want to show an heatmap on a website but the circle are colorless.

I've tried on other browser such as firefox and chrome and on these it work fine. This problem occur only on edge browser.

I juste use the example of the official website :
https://www.patrick-wied.at/static/heatmapjs/example-minimal-config.html

This is what i got on edge :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/vbC1n.png

this is what i got on firefox and what is expected on edge :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qg8VK.png

Answer (score 0):

According to the FAQ page, Edge is not specifically supported:

https://www.patrick-wied.at/static/heatmapjs/frequently-asked-questions.html

Answer (score 0):

I try to check that official site of HeatmapJS and find that example on that site is displaying properly in MS Edge 44.17763.1.0.

I also make a test with another sample to check whether I can produce the issue or not. I find that it is also working without any issue.

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="semantic.css"><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css"><script type="text/javascript" src="http://codeorigin.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="heatmap.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script></head><body><div id="node"></div></body></html>
```

Full code example in link below.

[Here is a sample of heatmap](http://bl.ocks.org/zbryikt/7165066)

Output in Edge:

[image]

It looks like may be your code has any issue in it. I suggest you to make a test with this example to check whether it works properly or not.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have some issues when i try to test example. But live example work on Edge. So i think the problem come from my code but it's same code that i use for firefox and chrome...

Comment: If possible than you can try to post your full example code. We can try to test it on our side to reproduce the issue. It may help to narrow down the issue.